# $.ajax não responde

Tags: jquery, ajax

Código:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitbuy").click(function () {
        alert("clicou no submitbuy");
        var emailc = $("#emailc").val();
        alert("variavel emailc atribuida: " + emailc);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://meusite.com/cadastro.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#forms").serialize(),
            success: function () {
                alert("entrou no success ajax");
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    alert("forms foi submit");
                    $("#forms").submit();
                } // if
                else {
                    alert("forms não foi submit, alert data");
                    alert(data);
                } // else
            } // success
        }); // ajax
    }); // submitbuy.click
}); // document.ready
</script>
```

O que acontece:
Exibi os dois primeiros alertas,(usei-os como debug) ps: no firebug não aponta erro algum neste código acima.
Mas não exibi o terceiro alerta(o que está dentro do success do $.ajax).

Qual será o problema? Tenho um outro código em ajax nessa mesma página, e ela cumpre com seu papel, já vasculhei todos os possíveis erros, mas nada achei..

EDIT:
Código do formulário, para deixar algo mais concreto:
Código do formulário está assim, é bem simples, apenas para capturar o e-mail:

```
<form action="https://www.meusite.com/paginax" method="POST" id="forms" name="forms">
   <input name="emailc" id="emailc" placeholder="seu melhor email!" id="emailc" type="text">
</form>
```

o input fica fora do formulário, do tipo button, apenas para abrir a função para posteriormente ser submetido no AJAX.

Comment: Acho que te falta um argumento aqui: `success: function(){`... devia ser `success: function(data){`. Senõ isto `if(data.length==0){` dá erro.

Comment: Indentar o código, ajudaria a ler ele...

Comment: `#submitbuy` é um botão `<input type="submit"...>` ou um link?

Comment: Sergio, estava faltando, coloquei denovo, mas não resolveu, deve ser porquê nem chegou a entrar no success e por isso não apontou o erro no firebug.

Guilherme, é um input do tipo button, `<input type="button">` e ele está fora do formulário, porquê a ideia é que o formulário não seja submetido, e sim que passe por este código acima quando alguém clicar no `submitbuy`, para sim posteriormente ser submetido usando o ajax.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus eu sei que não deve ser submetido, a questão é que poderia ser uma falha e por isto fiz tal pergunta. Veja a minha resposta.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus recebes algum dos alerts dentro do `success`?

Comment: Sergio, não recebo, por isso desconfio que não estejas entrando no success, o erro deve estar antes, mas não enxergo..

Comment: Código do formulário, para deixar algo mais concreto:
Código do formulário está assim, é bem simples, apenas para capturar o e-mail:
`<form action="https://www.meusite.com/paginax" method="POST" id="forms" name="forms">
<input name="emailc" id="emailc" placeholder="seu melhor email!" id="emailc" type="text">
</form>`

Comment: sabes se o ajax está a chegar ao PHP? (`'https://meusite.com/cadastro.php'`)

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Como eu disse na resposta, o pode ser um problema ou outro, como não é problema com `type=submit`, então é um problema com a requisição e como você não usou `error:` se ocorrer um erro na requisição você não irá saber, portanto use `erro:` ou `.fail()` como nos exemplos que passei :)

Comment: Olhei no console(aba All) do FireBug, e me deparei nisto, quando cliquei no botão `#submitbuy`:
*Pedido entre origens bloqueado: a política de mesma origem proíbe a leitura de recursos remotos em meusite.com.br/action.php. Isto pode ser corrigido movendo-se o recurso para o mesmo domínio ou ativando o CORS.*

Logo percebi que, a URL do meu site estava com www.meusite.com.br e eu estava requisitando para meusite.com.br/action.php.

Comment: Sim, o **www.** faltando, fez com o que a origem e o destino da requisição fossem diferentes, e com isso, por padrão, o servidor bloqueou a requisição dando aquele erro logo acima.

@Guilherme, agradeço pela sugestão do `error: function(err) { alert(err) }`, não havia pensado nessa possibilidade de pegar o erro, caso ocorresse.Agradeço também ao restante que se dispôs a me ajudar, mas como viram, o erro ia além do código, o servidor bloqueou por padrão essa requisição.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus pois, eu devia ter visto isso mas também me passou. Em vez de `https://meusite.com/cadastro.php` tens de usar caminhos relativos. Muda para `/cadastro.php`.

Comment: @Sergio, verdade, já que se o site não estiver configurado para reescrever a url(acredito ser possível pelo .htaccess), o usuário pode entrar tanto pelo www., quanto sem o www, então a melhor alternativa, para ambos os casos, é usar o /cadastro.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelos comentários do código, venho a presumir que você está usando algo como

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="submitbuy">
</form>
```

Podem estar ocorrendo *três* problemas:

1. Ao clicar no botão a página pode estar dando refresh e isto aborta a requisição ajax.
2. Se você não estiver usando botão `"submit"`, pode estar ocorrendo de haver um problema no ajax, portanto você deve usar o callback `error:`
3. (Conforme o próprio autor da questão encontrou @AlexandreC.Caus) Você provavelmente está usando url inteira, quando apenas o PATH seria o mais recomendável.
   Pode-se usar assim: `url: '/cadastro.php'` caminho absoluto.
   Ou caminho relativo: `url: 'cadastro.php'`
   A vantagem é que se o nome do dominio mudar os seus códigos ainda irão funcionar sem precisar fazer modificações, isto também ajuda com diferenças entre `https` e `http`
4. Como o @bfavaretto informou, não foi definido o argumento data

Para tentar pular ambos problemas, tente algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitbuy").click(function () {
        alert("clicou no submitbuy");
        var emailc = $("#emailc").val();
        alert("variavel emailc atribuida: " + emailc);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cadastro.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#forms").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {//Adicionado o argumento data
                alert("entrou no success ajax");
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    alert("forms foi submit");
                    $("#forms").submit();
                }
                else {
                    alert("forms não foi submit, alert data");
                    alert(data);
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {//Detecta erros na requisição
                alert(err);
            }
        });
        return false;//Bloqueia redirecionar em caso de type=submit
    });
});
```

O `error:` (ou `fail`) é obrigatorio, pois se houver problema de comunicação com o servidor ou com a internet (ISP), só ele vai poder relatar isto para você.

Note que a versão mais atual do ajax está incentivando o uso de [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), isto não tem haver com o seu problema é **apenas** uma dica, portanto se você quiser pode começar a usar assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://meusite.com/cadastro.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#forms").serialize()
}).done(function (data) {//Equivalente ao success (Adicionado o argumento data)
    alert("entrou no success ajax");
    if (data.length == 0) {
        alert("forms foi submit");
        $("#forms").submit();
    } else {
        alert("forms não foi submit, alert data");
        alert(data);
    }
}).fail(function (err) {//Equivalente ao error
    alert(err);
});
```

Comment: Boa, mas o botão é <input type="button"> e ele está fora do formulário, a ideia é que, ao clicar neste botão, o formulário não é submetido, e sim passe pelo AJAX, para posteriormente, ser submetido por lá.

Código do formulário está assim, é bem simples, apenas para capturar o e-mail:
`<form action="https://www.meusite.com/paginax" method="POST" id="forms" name="forms">
<input name="emailc" id="emailc" placeholder="seu melhor email!" id="emailc" type="text">
</form>`

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Não importa, isto era só uma teoria, como eu respondi aquilo antes do seu comentário, veja que a resposta diz assim: "Podem estar ocorrendo dois problemas" ou seja é um ou é outro, já que não é um problema com `type=submit` então teste o segundo problema. :)

Comment: Para isso que você está falando de não enviar o formulário, você pode deixar seu botão dentro do formulário com o valor submit, basta que no evento de click() bo botão você adicione a função event.preventDefault(); Assim o formulário não será enviado...

Comment: Pode ser também um erro porque `data` não está definido dentro do callback.

Comment: Olhei no console(aba All) do FireBug, e me deparei nisto, quando cliquei no botão `#submitbuy`:
*Pedido entre origens bloqueado: a política de mesma origem proíbe a leitura de recursos remotos em meusite.com.br/action.php. Isto pode ser corrigido movendo-se o recurso para o mesmo domínio ou ativando o CORS.*

Logo percebi que, a URL do meu site estava com www.meusite.com.br e eu estava requisitando para meusite.com.br/action.php.

Comment: Sim, o **www.** faltando, fez com o que a origem e o destino da requisição fossem diferentes, e com isso, por padrão, o servidor bloqueou a requisição dando aquele erro logo acima.

@Guilherme, agradeço pela sugestão do `error: function(err) { alert(err) }`, não havia pensado nessa possibilidade de pegar o erro, caso ocorresse.Agradeço também ao restante que se dispôs a me ajudar, mas como viram, o erro ia além do código, o servidor bloqueou por padrão essa requisição.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus Formule uma resposta então. Com algo assim. "Usei `meusite.com`, mas o correto seria `www.meusite`", ou então se você quiser considerar a minha resposta, eu adicionei alguns detalhes. Note: Você pode sim responder a suas próprias perguntas, isto pode vir a ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: @waghcwb Obrigado, o `return false;` do exemplo deve equivaler já a isto.